# Cannot extend partition in CentOS 6. Second partition is preventing it

Tags: centos, partition

I have a server on AWS EC2 that was set up by a sysadmin I hired.  I'm running very low on my /dev/xvda1 partition (where we keep the website code, assets, etc), and I've been looking to extend this.  I already followed [these steps](https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2014/01/02/how-to-resize-the-root-partition-in-linux-on-amazon-ec2/) to create a larger volume, but **sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1** says **The filesystem is already 1309289 blocks long.  Nothing to do!** which I'm assuming is due to there being a /dev/xvda2 partition.

I also tried to follow the instructions at the [bottom of this link](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=539484), however, I don't think I can extend it because /dev/xvda2 is in the way (which is used to store hourly MySQL snapshot backups).

I know my way around, but I do need someone to outline step-by-step on how to do this as I am a developer and not a sysadmin.  Can someone please help me add more space to /dev/xvda1?

```
[root@app2 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      5.0G  4.4G  348M  93% /
tmpfs           498M     0  498M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda2       15G  4.7G  9.5G  33% /var/backup
[root@app2 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/xvda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc637450e

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1               1         652     5237158+  83  Linux
/dev/xvda2             653        2611    15734330   83  Linux
[root@app2 ~]# fdisk /dev/xvda

WARNING: DOS-compatible mode is deprecated. It's strongly recommended to
         switch off the mode (command 'c') and change display units to
         sectors (command 'u').

Command (m for help): u
Changing display/entry units to sectors

Command (m for help): p

Disk /dev/xvda: 26.8 GB, 26843545600 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3263 cylinders, total 52428800 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc637450e

    Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/xvda1              63    10474379     5237158+  83  Linux
/dev/xvda2        10474380    41943039    15734330   83  Linux

Command (m for help): ^C
[root@app2 ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1      5.0G  4.4G  348M  93% /
tmpfs           498M     0  498M   0% /dev/shm
/dev/xvda2       15G  4.7G  9.5G  33% /var/backup
[root@app2 ~]# sudo resize2fs /dev/xvda1
resize2fs 1.41.12 (17-May-2010)
The filesystem is already 1309289 blocks long.  Nothing to do!
```

Answer (score 4):

Your simpleset solution here is likely to be to move the website data and assets into /dev/xvda2, reconfigure your webserver DocumentRoot(s) to point to it, and restart your web services.

If you have SELinux enables you will have to ensure that the files are correctly labeled (user_home_t) and set a boolean httpd_enable_homedirs.

Answer (score 2):

You could increase the size of `/dev/xvda1` by going into `fdisk`, deleting `/dev/xvda2` partition which will then be unusable, then in fdisk remove partition `/dev/xvda1`(but remember starting and ending blocks of the disk), then create a new `/dev/xvda1` on the excactly the same start block, but on a bigger/higher end block. After this you could grow your `/dev/xvda1` file system as the partition that it's on now is bigger.

But if you do this I recommend you back up because it is easy to screw up and then you will have ruined the box.

However, you may have to reboot of you have `/dev/xvda` mounted on `/`.

I would fix a new server in aws, get it sized as you want it to be and then migrate onto that one.